# Classified page - Better solution for image retrieval? n * scandir() OR n* mysql queries or full join?

Tags: php, mysql

I have classified ads webpage ( php 7.4 & pdo -mysqli) which is currently redesigned.

The ads and images data (path, name, size, user_id(indexed), classified_id(indexed)) are stored in different tables.

I have  a LOT of database and filesystem reads and very few writes.
writes:reads  1:1000 or more

I have a logical path for the storage of the images of each specific ad so that i will have less than 1000 directories in one directory

```
/{ 3 first digits of userid}/{remaining digits of user-id }/{classified -id}/ here are the images    
the thumbnails are in /tn
```

So i know the path of each image from the values in the table.

**MY QUESTION**

I have to retrieve all thumbnails when the classified's category page is displayed.

I have three possibilities:

1.) Do a one scandir() per classified ad  in the corresponding directory and output all images - (echo the file names (filtered by ending: jpeg) in the HTML.

2.) DO a one MYSQL query per classified ad  (e.g. 30 per page) and get all image names by searching for user and classified_id  (both indexed)

3.) Do a full join but then i will get a lot of redundant data as i will get 10 results for classified ads with 10 images with all classified fields - this data is only transferred on the same machine but it feels wrong.
Then i have only ONE SQL query but a lot of data in the result.

**What is the faster or better solution?**

Or is there a **DIFFERENT**  much better solution?
Performance is very important as the pages are indexed and speed rated by search engines and there may be 100 images on one page.

Notes:
The images are not sensitive so their storage location does not need to be hidden.
It is not possible to browse these directories by just entering the path into the browser.
The image names are randomized.

Comment: Define criteria for "better", otherwise we it is impossible to objectively suggest an approach. From speed point of view, you have the data, you can test multiple approaches and identify which one is faster on your system.

Comment: The only way you'll get objective data on relative performance is by measuring performance on your system. You don't seem to have considered any caching strategies that might reduce the amount of processing required.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular  No, I did not have considered any server based caching stategies yet but i am open to suggestions.  I do take care that all images and CSS can be cached on the users devices, load all of them lazy but thats pretty everything.

Comment: @Shadow Yes you are right, but before implementing both I was interested if there is any existing knowledge on this topic out there.

Comment: The generic experience is not particularly helpful for specific use cases. If you have a query and it is slow, then we may be able to suggest ways of speeding it up if we know the exact data structure and indexes. However, judging whether a query on an unknown data structure would be "better" than a file system scan (particularly when "better" is not even defined) on your system is not possible. There cannot be existing knowledge out there - apart from your own.

Answer (score 1):

We really need to see the proposed schemas *and* proposed SQL statements.

"searching for user and classified_id (both indexed)" -- Which do you mean

```
WHER user_id = 124 AND classified_id = 55
```

which needs a composite `INDEX(user_id, classified_id)`, *not* two separate indexes.  I'm hinting that that meaning of "both" is efficient; other meanings are probably not.

In general, looking up 30 files involves 30 "opens".  But looking up 30 rows in one table takes one "open" (the database table is already open).

Images...  In general, you should build a `<img>` and let the browser go after the image asynchronously.  It is *possible* to build the actual image into the `<img>`, which *might* be useful for small thumbnails.  And there are other techniques for handling lots of small thumbnails.  But let's leave that for another discussion.

"full join" -- Does it have a `WHERE`?  `ORDRE BY` and `LIMIT`?  Even after answering those questions, we need to see the query in order to predict whether it *might* hit only 30 rows in each table, or have to scan all of one or both tables.

"On the same server".  I sometimes do 100 queries to build a single page or have 100 images on a page.  30 *may* work well; 100 *may* have a noticeable lag.  (Single server for everything.)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  I need the {user} and {ad_id} indexes in other contexts ayway so it was my idea to add {user_id} just as a additional security measure.  But probably i just query for {ad_id}.   In the meantime i recognized that  i need the database version anyway because that is the only efficient and clean  way to have a sorting order of the images which is important as only the first image will be display in the overview. But as i am just implemeting it and have most probably not fallen into all possible I will only answer my findings after having tested everything.

Comment: "Images... In general, you should build a <img> and let the browser go after the image asynchronously. "  I do this.

Comment: "looking up 30 files involves 30 "opens". But looking up 30 rows in one table takes one "open" "   ---    Is this also  correct if I have 30  different queries    'select a,b,c in  table where d=?'  ?

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig - One `SELECT` is only one "open" of a table, which is probably already "open", regardless of how many rows will be returned.  The `SELECT` can probably do the sort for nearly "free".